# Should I include product URLs in my Sitemap, if I have Google Shopping?

Tags: google, url, sitemap, shopping

Well, the title says it all, really. We already have Google Shopping, where they have data for all of our products in the product feed, including URLs. Should I still include the URLs to the products, when generating the XML for Google Sitemap?

And if not, then I guess I have to have one sitemap for Google, without the product URLs, and another sitemap for all the other search engines, which includes the product URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely include them in your main sitemap. You still want your product URLs indexed as fast as possible, and a sitemap will help with that.